# How to create a simple spinner in HTML? Or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Is possible to create a spinner in HTML? Only HTML? A tag maybe?

My HTML:

```
<label for="time">Tempo:</label>
<input type="text" name="time" id="time" value="" style="width: 150px;" />
```

If not can we use some jquery? Something like "datepicker"
or like this

```
$("#time").spinner({ options });
```

Something realy simple :D

I found this but i can't understand how to use it.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Spinner/spinner

**EDIT:**

IF I USE THIS:

```
<label for="time">Tempo:</label>
<input type="number" name="time" id="time" value="0" style="width: 150px;" />
```

(The diference is the input type)

Chrome automatically creates the spinner (+1/-1) but the same does not happen with firefox (and not tested on IE)

Why people still use other browsers?! :D

Comment: That spinner is a control to do things like +1/-1

Comment: @dougajmcdonald and that is what I want! I want to +1 and -1 the value of the input.

Comment: My apologies, from the un-edited question I was under the impression you wanted a loading gif type 'spinner'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/btburnett3/jquery.ui.spinner

**Load css and javascript using respective tags**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jSpinner/ui.spinner.js"></script>
.
.
.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jSpinner/ui.spinner.css" />


.
$("#time").spinner({
    min : 0,
    max : 100,
    showOn : 'both'
});
```

PS:please load jquery and jquery.ui plugin before loading the ui.spinner.js

Comment: But there is no native suport in jQuery UI ? 
(Only including jqueri.ui plugin and jquery)

Comment: Like I said on my EDIT if I use ( type="number" ) chrome automatically creates the spinner but the same does not happen on firefox (11) and I dont want to see on IE :(

Comment: this is ok but the licensing (GPL v2) makes it a pain in the butt to use on commercial products

Answer (score 5):

http://github.com/fgnass/spin.js

- No images
- no external CSS
- No dependencies
- Highly configurable
- Resolution independent
- Uses VML as fallback in old IEs
- Uses @keyframe animations, falling back to setTimeout()
- Works in all major browsers, including IE6
- Small footprint (~1.9K gzipped)

Comment: He meant an input field spinner with up and down arrows, not a loading spinner

Comment: You forgot: "Requires Node". I'm not sure its fair to say it has "No dependencies" when it requires a package on top of JS. I saw your solution and thought, "Nice! Perfect!.. Oh nvm it requires node"

Comment: If you mean nodejs, no, you're confusing that with TypeScript.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML code for the spinner box looks like this:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="50" step="2" value="0" size="6" name="cantitate">
```

The TYPE is "number". The MIN and MAX are the start and end values you want for the value. The STEP attribute is the increase or decrease in value when you click on the arrows. The VALUE is the default that appears in the box when the page loads, and also the value that is returned when the form is sent. SIZE refers to how wide you want the box.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [spinner](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138077/Spinner) from the upcoming jQuery UI 1.9, although you'd have to be happy with using the library in beta. [Here's a demo](http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/index.html#spinner).

Chrome (8) and Opera (11) [both use](http://www.coreservlets.com/html5-tutorial/input-types.html#number-supported) the native HTML5 spinner, but it's ugly IMO.